# Displaying other document extensions in a PHP/mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

OK this is my first post here so, hello! and please go easy on me if this is a simple solution. 
I am creating a document database using apache2,mysql and php. I have only had previous experience with html,css and a small amount of javascript so this has been a steep learning curve and a good challenge for me.
I have successfully created the database and uploaded documents into it. i can search and link to the documentment required in a html/php screen but i only seem to be able to use/search, recall one extension type. this would be either .PHP, .PDF, .html, or .docx etc. In reality not all documents are or will be PDF's, below is my script:

```
/* -- end of connection script --*/

if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

    $get_value = $_GET['user_query'];

    if($get_value=='') {

        echo "<center id='alert'><b>nothing in the search field</b></center>";
        exit();
    }
    if($get_value=='Search...'){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $result_query = "SELECT * from search WHERE site_keywords LIKE '%$get_value%' OR site_title LIKE '%$get_value%' OR site_description LIKE '%$get_value%' ";
    $run_result = mysql_query($result_query);
?>

    <h3 class="total"><?php echo $row_result; ?>Results for '<?php echo $get_value; ?>'</h3>

<?php

    if(mysql_num_rows($run_result)<1) {

        echo "<center id='alert'><b>Oops! no search results found</b></center>";
        exit();

    }

    while($row_result=mysql_fetch_array($run_result)) {
        $site_id=$row_result['site_id'];
        $site_title=$row_result['site_title'];
        $site_link=$row_result['site_link'];
        $site_description=$row_result['site_description'];
        $site_file=$row_result['site_file']; 

        echo"<div class='results'>
            <h3><a href='$site_id.php' target='_blank'>$site_title</a></h3> 
            <p align='justify'>$site_description</p>
            </div>";
    }
}

?>
```

as you can see from the echo results the href file requires an extension (in this case .php) to correctly display a .php document but not other extension types. If i change this to .pdf it will display the .pdf but not .php and so on. I am at a loss.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ api

Comment: You need to store the file extension as well in the database.

Comment: Shadow, many many thanks such a simple solution as i thought it seems i was looking a bit too deep. All files can now be called. Also the $site doesn't need the .php extension. Strawberry, thank you for your input I will look to replace the mysql_api moving forward. As i said i am relatively new to this side of code so all a learning experience for me.